# lvalue required as increment operand when returning by value

Tags: c++

```
class cls
{ 
    int x;
public: 
    cls(int i=-20) { x=i; }
    int f() { return x; }

int main()
{ 
    cls a(14);
    int b;
    b=a.f()++;
    cout<<b;
    return 0;
}
```

I'm getting "lvalue required as increment operand" at this line `b=a.f()++;`. If I change it to `b=++a.f();` I get the same error, but if I change it to `b=a.f()+1;` it's working fine. How does the compiler thinks when it has a prefix `++` or a postfix `++` operand to do? What's the difference between `a++` (or `++a`) and `a=a+1` (where `a` is of type int, let's say)?

Comment: You're not saying `a = a + 1;`, you're saying `b = a + 1;`. There's a difference.

Comment: c++03? What compiler and options?

Comment: You are missing at least one `}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Think of it this way:

```
expression++
```

is a shorthand for

```
expression = expression + 1
```

It is **not** a shorthand for

```
expression + 1
```

Now expand it with your function call:

```
a.f() = a.f() + 1
```

The above does not make sense, unless `f()` returns something that you can assign, e.g. a reference. Therefore the expression is invalid.

However, if your function returned by reference, the assignment would be possible:

```
int& f() {
    return x;
}
```

Now both expressions `a.f()++` and `a.f() = a.f()+1` make perfect sense: it's `x` inside `a` that gets modified, so your program would compile.

Answer (score 4):

The result of `f()` is a **temporary**.  You cannot increment a temporary integer...

Comment: But why I can do "b=a.f()+1;" ? a.f() would still be a temporary...that's what I don't understand.

Comment: @AlexandruAndrei: Because you're not incrementing anything there.  Remember that `++x` is the same as `x = x + 1`.